# Is there any way to rearrange excel data without copy paste?

Tags: python, excel, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have an excel file that contain country name and dates as column name.

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+
| country | 20/01/2020 | 21/01/2020 | 22/01/2020 |
+--------- ------------+------------+------------+
| us      |   0        |   5        |       6    |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+
| Italy   | 20         |   23       |      33    |
+--------- ------------+------------+------------+
| India   |   0        |   0        |       6    |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+
```

But i need to arrange column names country, date, and count. Is there any way to rearrange excel data without copy paste.

final excel sheet need to look like this

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| country | date       | count      | 
+--------- ------------+------------+
| us      | 20/01/2020 |   0        | 
+---------+------------+------------+
| us      | 21/01/2020 |   5        |   
+---------+------------+------------+
| us      | 22/01/2020 |   6        |    
+---------+------------+------------+
| Italy   | 20/01/2020 |   20       |     
+--------- ------------+------------+
| Italy   | 21/01/2020 |   23       |     
+--------- ------------+------------+
| Italy   | 22/01/2020 |   33       |      
+--------- ------------+------------+
| India   | 20/01/2020 |   0        | 
+---------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: If not is there any way to rearrange using **python**

Comment: It is a simple `unpivot` operation using `Power Query`, available in Excel 2010+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Pivot is the best way, but if you want to use formulas:
In **F1** enter:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/3,0))
```

and copy downward.  In **G1** enter:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,3)+1)
```

and copy downward.  **H1** enter:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$4,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/3,0),MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,3)+1)
```

and copy downward

[image]

The ***3*** in these formulas is because we have ***3*** dates in the original table.

Comment: It works for small table. Table that i need to arrange is very large one.

Comment: if the date change to 1/20/2020 second formula is not working

Comment: @udaraNadeeshani  The formulas must be adjusted to match the table size.  You will have to change the ***3*** as well as the table arguments **$A$2:$A$4** and **$B$1:$D$1** and **$B$2:$D$4**

Comment: i changed it. for date 21/1/2020 formula is working.  for 1/20/2020  its not working

Comment: i change the code into ``` =INDEX($E$1:$BL$1,MOD(ROW()-1,60)+1) ```.

Answer (score 3):

Unpivot using Power Query:

- `Data --> Get & Transform --> From Table/Range`
- Select the `country` column

  - Unpivot Other columns
- Rename the resulting `Attribute` and `Value` columns to `date` and `count`
- Because the Dates which are in the header are turned into Text, you may need to change the `date` column type to `date`, or, as I did, to `date using locale`

[image]

#### M-Code

```
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"country", type text}, {"20/01/2020", Int64.Type}, {"21/01/2020", Int64.Type}, {"22/01/2020", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"country"}, "date", "count"),
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {{"date", type date}}, "en-150")
in
    #"Changed Type with Locale"
```

Comment: i can,t understand how to do this. I select only country column and i cant understand the rest of steps.

Comment: @udaraNadeeshani Then just paste the M-Code into the Advanced Editor, and change `Table2` to whatever the name of your Table is in your Workbook.